# problem with cludinary upload api with q_ parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, cloudinary

i am building a website where user can upload some videos, if the video is too large i want to reduce its quality and save to my cloudinary account.

this code :

return fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${CLOUD_NAME}/${type === 'img' ? 'image' : 'video'}/upload`

uploads the video as expected, but when i add somethin like q_20 or q_auto in the end:

return fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${CLOUD_NAME}/${type === 'img' ? 'image' : 'video'}/upload/q_20`

it gives me a 404 error as well as "blocked by cors" error.

i don't know if that is important, but this code is written in the frontend using react and running on localhost3000.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `q_20` at the end of the URL returns 404 because this makes the URL not match any valid API endpoint on Cloudinary.

Based on your post, I understand you're trying to transform the video to `quality: 20` before it is stored in your Cloudinary account. If that is the case, then this is called an [incoming transformation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformations_on_upload#incoming_transformations) and you would need to set that `transformation` parameter in the request body rather than appending to the API URL.

For example, you could send it as FormData like:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', <your image or video URL/blob etc>);
formData.append('transformation', 'q_20');
```

Then send the `formData` as part of the body of your `fetch()` call.

I'm not sure which plan on Cloudinary you're on, but at least on the Free plan, the maximum file size of videos you can upload is 100MB. If you have videos above that which you want to upload then either resizing the video down (e.g. from HD to SD resolution) or lowering the quality should help with that.

Comment: Thank you. I want to upload a video that weights 120 MB on the free plan, can i use the formData.append('transformation', 'q_20') in order to upload it in lower quality to cloudinary or should i compress/reduce video quality by myself first and only then upload it?  In addition, i see that i can only use transformations on singned uploads and did't understand what that means and if i can or can't use signed uploads directly from my client side with the fetch request?

Comment: You can do either of those - however, I wouldn't add q_20 as that will significantly lower the quality. Instead, you can use 'quality' => 'auto' (q_auto).

Comment: In regards to the "transformation" parameter - you can only set that on Signed Uploads. You can perform Signed uploads from the client-side, however, since that requires the generation of a Signature which itself requires your API Secret, the signature generation itself should be performed only on the server side. You could make a request from your client-side app to your server to get the Signature and then send the upload request from the client side. Or you could send the file to your server and upload the video from there. Cloudinary SDKs use Signed Uploads by default.